# CodeBuild YML formatting and syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I've got a codebuild project up and running on an ubuntu server to clone rds database servers from snapshots.  A lot of it is working as expected but when i try and include the following like in the buildspec.yml the job falls over and it doesn't like the command.

Guessing the job doesn't like the formatting but bit stumped where to go with it

`- while [ $(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier mysql-dev-20201009|grep -c '"Status": "available"') -eq 0 ]; do echo "sleep 60s"; sleep 60; done`

Here's the full buildspec file:

```
Version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.7
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pip install --upgrade pip
      - pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
      - export SOURCEDBENV=mysql-dev
      - export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
      - export TARGETDBENV=$SOURCEDBENV-$DATE
      - echo $TARGETDBENV
      - export PREARNSNAP=$(aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots --db-cluster-identifier $SOURCEDBENV --query="reverse(sort_by(DBClusterSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime))[0]|DBClusterSnapshotArn" )
      - export ARNSNAP=`echo $PREARNSNAP | tr -d '"'` 
      - echo $ARNSNAP
      - aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot --snapshot-identifier $ARNSNAP --db-cluster-identifier $TARGETDBENV --engine aurora-mysql
      - aws rds create-db-instance --db-instance-identifier $TARGETDBENV --db-instance-class db.t3.medium --db-subnet-group-name db_subnet_grp_2019 --engine aurora-mysql --db-cluster-identifier $TARGETDBENV
      - while [ $(aws rds describe-db-cluster-endpoints --db-cluster-identifier $DBNAME | grep -c available) -eq 0 ]; do echo "sleep 60s"; sleep 60; done
      - echo "Temp db ready"
      - export ENDPOINT=$(aws rds describe-db-cluster-endpoints --db-cluster-identifier $DBIDENTIFIER| grep "\"Endpoint\"" | grep -v "\-ro\-" | awk -F '\"' '{print $4}')
      - echo $ENDPOINT
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo proceed db connection to $ENDPOINT
      - echo proceed db migrate update, DDL proceed here
      - echo proceed application test, CRUD test run here
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo $DBNAME
```

Comment: Can you share more of your `buildspec.yml` file so we can see where in your template this is running in?

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can take advantage of the [`wait`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/index.html) command in the AWS cli?

Rather than use the `while` loop, simply [wait](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/wait/db-instance-available.html) for the db instance to be available

```sh
aws rds wait db-instance-available --filters Name=db-cluster-id,Values=$TARGETDBENV
```